# Não estou conseguindo atribuir valores a variáveis

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou tentando atribuir valores a algumas variáveis e não estou obtendo sucesso, na chamada de uma função passo um parâmetro o qual estou recebendo corretamente, mas tentar passar esse e mais um valor como parâmetros não consigo.

Fiz isso:

```
function BuscaDados(pIdAgenda) {    
    var params = {
        Operacao: 'BuscaUnica',
        pIdAgenda: pIdAgenda
    };
}
```

Executando o `console.log` da variável enviada para a função BuscaDados o valor está correto, mas ao tentar atribuí-las para `params` e executando o `console.log` o que obtenho é `[object Object]`

Comment: coloca assim `console.log(params)` que ele vai retornar todo o conteúdo do objeto é isso que quer ver ? Por que do jeito que você atribuiu **Operacao** e **pIdAgenda** a variavel **params** ela se tornou sim um Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function BuscaDados(pIdAgenda) {    
var params = {
    Operacao: 'BuscaUnica',
    pIdAgenda: pIdAgenda
}; 
return params;
```

}

BuscaDados(123);

Answer (score -1):

function BuscaDados(pIdAgenda) {
var params = {
Operacao: 'BuscaUnica',
pIdAgenda: pIdAgenda
};
return params;

Comment: Sua resposta é [igual à outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82920/100416)...